# Create transparent div on top of Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

This is probably a newbie question but I hope someone can help me. I'm creating a website, with a background changing and with a  little transparency div with the information and of course a navbar. I have the navbar and the background (with Owl Carousel) like I want but I don't know how I can create that div in the center. Thanks!
https://jsfiddle.net/pw1dk40p/

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/sliders/Slide.jpg)">
</div>
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/sliders/Slide2.jpg)">
</div>
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/sliders/Slide3.jpg)">
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain more about what does this phrase mean: `create that div in the center`. How it should look like? https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/s8c81na8/

Comment: Like this http://oi67.tinypic.com/n37uav.jpg